# Spring boot store dynamic key value pair list in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using spring boot. I want to store dynamic collection with name value pair using model in mondo db.

How to store below json in mongodb?

```
{
"id":"123456",
"name":"test",
"attributes":[
    {"name":"1"}, 
    {"color":"red"},
    {"size":"small"}
],
.....    

}
```

Here attributes is dynamic hashmap.

how to create model in spring boot for above?

```
public class Records {
    @Id
    String id;

    @Field("name")
    String name;

    @Field("attributes")
    private BasicDBObject variantAttrs;
}
```

above is creating json object of attributes and not json array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mapping an array of attributes to BasicDBObject, we need to map it to List.

```
public class Records {
    @Id
    String id;

    @Field("name")
    String name;

    @Field("attributes")
    private List<BasicDBObject> variantAttrs;
}
```

Comment: It gives result like below: 
{
attributes:[{
"name":"value",
"name2":"value2"
}]
}